# Running time for the count-function in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a DataFrame X in sparkR. X contain column with ID =  1 2 3 1 2 3 9 ... and a score for each entry: score = 1241 233 20100 ....

To find all the scores for ID is therefore

```
s=filter(X, X$ID==1)
```

and then we get all scores for ID 1 which we can take the sum of.

I want to know the number of ID=1 in X so I use the 'count' function in SparkR

```
count(s)
```

but this take very long time to calculate. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Assuming that we have arrange or sorted X so ID = 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 .....
then maybe there is a better alternative to avoid to do count(s) .

Comment: Do you want to know the amount of elements for every ID? And more or less, how big is your DataFrame?

Comment: Yes I want to know the amount of elements for every ID. My DataFrame is about 100 000 times 2.

Answer (score 0):

By aggregating on ID and counting how many items there are, you immediately get the result for all ID's, however, with only 100000 rows it shouldn't take long at all!

```
countedData <- agg(groupBy(X, "ID"), count = n(X[["score"]]))
```

Comment: WHen I type that it say "ID" not found? Are you using a package?

Comment: Sorry, it should have quotes around ID, I have edited it.

Comment: So now countedData is a DataFrame and not a number like count(s). It say "DataFrame[ID: string, count: bigint]"

Comment: Yes, now you should collect it and then you have a data.frame with the count of every ID.

Comment: When I type collect(countedData) it goes on and will take some time like count(s). I think it will take the same time about 30 min.

Comment: I would expect this to be much faster on 100000 rows. You could stil check the number of partitions you use, but I am afraid this won't speed it up neither.